# Why can't I move second camera permanently?

Tags: animation, 3d-view, camera

I'm trying to add a second camera to my scene, but when I move it to a different angle, it reverts back to the original position when I press play.

I added markers and binded cameras to each marker too.

See before and after pics:

[image: blender camera scene]
[image: blender camera scene]

Here is my blend file: [image]

Comment: have you created a keyframe for it?

Comment: hi @moonboots, no I haven't. I'm following a tutorial, which didn't demonstrate adding any frames! Should I be?

Comment: There are definitely keyframes on the timeline : Look for the rotated white squares. You can delete them by clicking on it and right click > Delete keyframes

Comment: yet we can see some keyframes, what are they for? maybe share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I have added my file to my question there. Yes, there are some keyframes, not sure why they are there to be honest - think they are for the floor object, which expands at the inserted keyframes. Really new to blender so bear with me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your camera selected, open a *Dope Sheet* window, enable the *Only Show Selected* option in order to see only the keyframes of the selected object, as you can see you've created a keyframe for your camera, select it and delete with <kbd>X</kbd>:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I will try this! Do I add keyframes for the cameras then after?

Comment: yes it's a good idea if you want to make sure that it won't move accidentally

Comment: Thanks again! :D